# Spring Boot 1.4 -> 1.5 suddenly checks for hostname

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm migrating a Spring Boot 1.4 App to Spring Boot 1.5

For some unknown reason, Spring now checks for the hostname supplied and returns a bad-request in case its not localhost..

This gives me a 400

```
curl -X POST \
  http://docker_host:8080/api/portal/v1/login \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "customerId": "0",
        "username": "domdorn",
        "password": "mypass"
}'
```

and this gives me the desired response:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/api/portal/v1/login \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "customerId": "0",
        "username": "domdorn",
        "password": "mypass"
}'
```

both "docker_host" and "localhost" resolve to 127.0.0.1

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.5.13.RELEASE brings 8.5.31 version of tomcat.
This version of tomcat puts a restriction on the hostname that name cannot contain any numeric or ‘-‘ in hostname extension

For example, any hostname test.example3 would be considered as invalid but test3.example is a valid entry.

This is the known issue in tomcat 8.5.31 and has been fixed in 8.5.32 version of tomcat (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62371).

Unfortunately, no release of Spring Boot currently supports the version of tomcat that contains the fix.

Comment: I've marked your answer as the right one, as it explains the underlying problem, although I already found a fix.

Comment: You could use Jetty instead of Tomcat as a workaround until Spring Boot fixes it

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the issue. 
The underscore `_` is a forbidden character in a hostname, thus probably Tomcat in the newer version rejected the request all together, without even letting it go down to spring.